# Expected a list of items but got type \"int\"."

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

**abby_res_data.py**

```
from django.db import models
import uuid # Required for unique book instances
# Create your models here.
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
import shutil
from .abbyuser import userData
from django.utils import timezone

class image_parsing(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,null=False,editable=True)
    user_pk_id = models.ForeignKey(userData, related_name='fk_id', on_delete = models.CASCADE, db_column='user_pk_id' , null=True)
    request = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, editable=True)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, editable=True)
    response = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, editable=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True, editable=True, max_length=30)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True, editable=True, max_length=30)
```

**user_credits.py**

```
from django.db import models
import uuid # Required for unique book instances
# Create your models here.
from datetime import datetime

class userCredit(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,help_text='unique user_id',default=uuid.uuid4,null=False)
    user_pk_id = models.IntegerField(null=True,editable=True)
    certification = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True,editable=True)
    awardStatus = (
        ('V','VIP'),
        ('VV', 'VVIP'),
        ('VV', 'VVVIP'),
    )
    user_level_status = models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=awardStatus,blank=True,default='V',help_text='Award Level')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, editable=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True, editable=True, max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**model_image_serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from ..models import image_parsing
from ..Serializers import abbyserializers


class imageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_pk_id = abbyserializers()
    class Meta:
        model = image_parsing
        fields = ('id', 'request', 'filename',  'response',  'created_date',  'updated_date', 'user_pk_id')
```

**model_serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from ..models import userData

class abbyserializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = userData
        fields = ("user_id","userName", "user_address", "user_pincode", "user_status", "created_date", "updated_date", "user_level_status")
```

When I am trying to save data it throws an error:

```
"user_pk_id": {
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Expected a list of items but got type \"int\"."
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please use CamelCase in your classes' names

Comment: What's probably happening is that, instead of passing a list of the data the `abbyserializer` wants to serialize, you're passing it an integer, and `abbyserializer` can't serialize an integer. You need to erase `user_pk_id = abbyserializers()` from `imageSerializer`

Comment: when i am removing user_pk_id = abbyserializers() from imageserializer, It just save the data and works fine but then how will i get the joined data for these two serializers, Please suggest.Then how should i join two serializers.

Comment: You can't do it with only one serializer. Make one serializer for saving data and another one for retrieving it.

Comment: I am new to DRF but technical it doesn't make sense to create new serializer and also  i have studied lot of queries previously in Stack Overflow and there is no update for new serializers to fetch data. Can you please elaborate the same so that i can get something deducible.

Comment: It does make sense, technically, to create a new serializer, because the only other thing you can do is override the `create` and `update` methods of the serializer, along with the validators, and create a huge mess of hundreds of lines of code just for the sake of not creating a new serializer in 5-10 lines. Please, make a serializer for retrieving data and one for saving it.